# oracle forms how to keep checkbox checked after execute_query

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

Form with multi record datablock, that updates table by calling PL/SQL for checked rows.  Need to be able to retain checkbox checked state AND position after execute_query.

Code on WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED to process all selected rows.

```
DECLARE
   l_cur_record  NUMBER;
   v_error       VARCHAR2 (1);
BEGIN
   l_top_record := GET_BLOCK_PROPERTY ('LOAD_DETAILS_LOG', TOP_RECORD);

   GO_BLOCK ('LOAD_DETAILS_LOG');
   FIRST_RECORD;

   LOOP
      IF :LOAD_DETAILS_LOG.select_chk = 'Y'
      THEN
         l_cur_record := :SYSTEM.CURSOR_RECORD;

         PK_LOAD_CHE.P_CHECK_FILES ( :LOAD_DETAILS_LOG.file_id,
                                    :LOAD_DETAILS_LOG.original_filename,
                                    :LOAD_DETAILS_LOG.fsy_code,
                                    :LOAD_DETAILS_LOG.received_date,
                                    v_error);
      END IF;

      EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';
      NEXT_RECORD;
   END LOOP;

   IF v_error = 'Y'
   THEN
      msg_alert ('Errors found in selected files. Please check Error Log',
                 'I',
                 FALSE);
      GO_BLOCK ('LOAD_DETAILS_ERRORS');
      EXECUTE_QUERY;
   ELSE
      GO_BLOCK ('LOAD_DETAILS_LOG');
      EXECUTE_QUERY (NO_VALIDATE);
   END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Need to be able to retain checkbox checked state AND position after execute_query.

If checkbox "state" means whether it is checked or not, then it has to be a **database item** (i.e. belong to a table). If it is an item which isn't based on table values, then executing a query can't know which checkboxes were checked (and which were not).

That answers the second part of a question as well.

Comment: Yes state means - checked or unchecked.    Can you give an example of how to use checkbox as a database item?

Comment: It has to be a column in a table, and then - in a form - you'd update its properties and set it to be based on that column.

Answer (score 0):

Like littlefoot said, you should make the checkbox a basetable item. If you can't do this or don't want to do this then you could keep the values of that are checked before the query in a temporary table or in an array.
After the query you can walk over each row and check in the array or temporary table if the value was checked and check it again.